# How to view my resources in Civilization VI with xbox one edition?

Tags: xbox-one, civilization-6

I know that the PC edition of civ 6 shows the list of resources like luxury resources on the top left when you point at it. But on xbox how to view it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer.

When you are on the game screen press RB to bring the menu with 'World Ranking'. The fourth item on this menu is 'List of Reports'. If you click on it, it opens up a pop up that contains 'Resources' as the second item. Select it & it will show your resources. Note: The last item is Global resources belonging to everyone.